# unix echo default argument

Tags: unix, echo

In my scripts I nearly always use escape sequences for colours:

```
R='\e[0m'
g='\e[0;32m'
echo -e "${g}green text${R}"
```

I'd like to make `-e` default behaviour so I can omit it. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup an [`alias`](http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html):

```
alias echo='echo -e'
```

With it active, you can omit the `-e`:

```
echo "${g}green text${R}"
```

Comment: was almost about to say it ;)

Comment: And you can override then this default with `-E` in case you need to disable escape sequences.

Comment: this will not work within a script unless you set `shopt -s expand_aliases` but beside this it's a working example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use an *alias* for that, and it works for many shells. But `bash` aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells, and you want it to be used for scripts, which are non-interactive.

Citing `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions

So you can use functions, but I'd call it differently, to avoid mistakes or infinite recursion:

```
myecho()
{
    echo -e "$@"
}
```

And if you are on it you can do better:

```
green_echo()
{
    echo -e "${g}$@${R}"
}
```

Or even better, you could get the color as first argument, shift it out of `$@` and use a switch to select the correct escape sequence. There are no limits, remember that the shell is a complete programming language.

Comment: @Maxime: I've just tested a script with `#!/bin/bash`, `alias foo=echo`, `foo bar`, and it says `line 3: foo: command not found`. I guess that you could use the shell option `expand_aliases`, but that's probably a bad idea...

Comment: For me, it works with /bin/sh, and it does not work with /bin/bash. Try changing your shebang?

Comment: @Maxime: Oh, right. So some shells (sh -> dash in my system) do expand aliases in scripts and some (bash) do not. I've updated my answer. Anyway, I wonder why the difference...

Comment: That's even worse actually. Bash interprets the shebang and changes its behavior whether it's /bin/sh or /bin/bash. I've tried changing the link /bin/sh to point to /bin/bash and I can see the same result.

Comment: @Maxime: Yeah, that's the POSIX mode, for compatibility with historical shells. You can get it also with `#!/bin/bash --posix`.